# Compute $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}$ without using derivatives

Tags: limits, exponential-function

How to compute $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}$ without using derivatives? Every method I can think of gives me some indeterminate form.

Comment: Do you consider the power series expansion of $e^x$ to be "using derivatives"?

Comment: $\displaystyle L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{0+x}-e^0}{x}$.

Comment: You are actually asking to compute $(e^x)'(0)$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that exponentials "go faster" than any polynomial?

Comment: @IrregularUser Yes.Ben Millwood, I have never used power series expansion yet.

Comment: Then I assume that you've come across the sandwich/squeeze rule. Try and bound the limit from above and below.

Comment: @IrregularUser Thanks, indeed I did use the rule. Still I have a hard time trying to find functions that would bound it to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $\ e^x-1=y, $ so $\ x=\ln(1+y)$ and $\ y\to0$ for $\ x\to0$

Now you have:
$$\ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y}{\ln(1+y)}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1}{\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1}{\ln(1+y)^{\frac{1}{y}}}$$

Putting $\ \frac{1}{y}=t,$ for $\ y\to0, t\to\infty$ , so you have:
$$\ \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{\ln(1+\frac{1}{t})^t}=\frac{1}{\ln(e)}=1$$

By definition of $\ e$.

Comment: That's one really clever solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Take $x=\dfrac1k$ and use the definition of $e$:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x=\lim_{k\to\infty}k(e^{1/k}-1)=\lim_{k\to\infty}k\left(\lim_{nk\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{nk}\right)^{nk/k}-1\right).$$

By the Binomial theorem, the inner limit expands as

$$1+\frac n{nk}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2k^2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!n^3k^3}\cdots,$$ which is bounded above by
$$1+\frac1k+\frac1{2k^2}+\frac1{3!k^3}\cdots$$

Then
$$1<k(e^{1/k}-1)<1+\frac1{2k}+\frac1{3!k^2}\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the Taylor expansion for $e^x$ and cancel out the x in the denominator and then put x =0,  to get 1 as the answer.

Comment: One might argue that Taylor expansion is equivalent to knowing the derivatives...

Comment: Yes you're right.